# Touchscreen calibration: touchscreen does not cover full display

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, touchscreen, xorg

I have purchased an industrial touchscreen monitor that supports Linux through PenMount drivers. The VGA video output (via HDMI adapter) works perfectly, and the USB touchscreen is perfectly configured from the start - except that the cursor cannot be moved from a small block in the middle of the display.

If I touch the screen near the bezel, the cursor will move to the closest point at the edge of the invisible boundary, but I cannot increase the size of this touch-cursor boundary to cover the whole screen. The vertices of this invisible block seem to be the calibration centre-marks of the `xinput_calibrator`

I have used `xinput_calibrator`, and updated the `99-calibration.conf` file, but to no avail. I have also installed the PenMount drivers, but in the linux kernel I compiled the `penmount.o` file is inexplicably missing, although the `penmount.c` file is present.

I have also tried to use the screen manufacturer's provided drivers, but their build files have not been able to execute, even after I corrected the paths to suit the Raspbian distro,

Any suggests on how to increase the allowable area of the touch cursor?

Versions:

Raspberry Pi 3B+

Linux version 4.19.55-v7+

gcc version 6.3.0 20170516

Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1